# Supremum of increasing net of operators on Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

Consider the following fragment of Murphy's  "$C^*$-algebras and operator theory".

[image]

Can someone explain how $\sup_\lambda u_\lambda$ is defined (is it just notation?) and why it exists?

Relevant definitions: $B(H)_{sa}$ are the self-adjoint operators in $B(H)$ and a net $(u_\lambda)$ in $B(H)$ converges strongly if and only if $\Vert u_\lambda(x) - u(x)\Vert \to 0$ for all $x \in H$.

Comment: Isn't it just the least upper bound w.r.t. the partial order $\le$ on self-adjoint operators? In other words, $u = \sup_\lambda u_\lambda$ means that $u_\lambda \le u$ for all $\lambda$, and for any $v \in H$ we have $u_\lambda \le v, \forall \lambda \implies u \le v$.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but I think Murphy defines $\sup_\lambda u_\lambda$ in the weak sense. That is, the $\sup_\lambda u_\lambda$ is the operator $v : H \to H$ characterized by 
$$
\langle v(x),y \rangle = \sup_\lambda \langle u_\lambda(x), y \rangle
$$
for any $x,y \in H$. Then of course, if $u_\lambda$ converges strongly to $u$, it follows from
$$
\|v(x)-u(x)\| \leq \| u_\lambda(x)-u(x)\|
$$
that $u=v$. However, what @mechanodroid just wrote might make more sense.

Comment: @mechanodroid Ah maybe yes! Thanks!

Comment: @mechanodroid Don't you mean $v = v^*$ instead of $v \in H$?

Comment: @user745578 Yeah, sure.

Comment: @mechanodroid Thanks again!

Comment: I see Hilbert space is sort of extended vector space allowing 'norms' and 'angle' and even calculus. Then 'operator' simply means extended 'linear map' (i.e. matrix)? http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/real/notes_2016-17/08a-ops_on_Hsp.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Sup" means "least upper bound". As the net is increasing, $u_\lambda\leq u$ for all $\lambda$; so $u$ is an upper bound.

If $u_\lambda\leq v$ for all $\lambda$, then
$$
\langle ux,x\rangle=\lim_\lambda\langle u_\lambda x,x\rangle\leq\langle vx,x\rangle. 
$$
So $u$ is below any upper bound for the net. Thus, $u$ is the least upper bound.